# Info for Aggadeta Tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The info for the [aggadeta tag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/aggadeta/info) is:

> Non-legal passages in the Talmud and other Rabbinic writings that use descriptive allegories and stories to convey fundamental truths about reality, as well as theological and moral lessons.

However, this statement about the deep significance of the aggadot seems more more reflective of the likes of Maharal than his predecessors (I am not unaware of Rambam's introduction to Helek). It certainly does not do a good job of reflecting the view that the aggadot were sometimes just used to wake up sleepy students, and the like.

(For a by no-means comprehensive survey of classical views on aggada/aggadeta/haggada/midrash/drash (terms used interchagably by Rishonim, see [Belief in midrashim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351))

I am therefore seeking an edit that avoids taking a stand on the issue (leaving that instead to the website itself.

Comment: We already have a [tag:agada-stories-legends] tag. Why does this one even exist?

Comment: Re "aggada/aggadeta/haggada/midrash/drash (terms used interchagably by Rishonim": I'm surprised. Did they not use the term "_midrash halacha_" to refer to things like _Sifra_? Or do they call things like _Sifra_ "_agada_"?

Comment: @msh210 They used the term Midrash broadly, much as we do today, such that it could be used to refer to anything from fantastic stories in the Talmud, to Tannaic halakhic compilations.

Comment: So... then _midrash_ and _agada_ were **not** used interchangeably?

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed. That is a separate issue to be sorted out. It should be noted that that tag has no guidance and is not at all clear if it is intended to include any old wives tales, stories in the Talmud, or something else.

Comment: @msh210 In most contexts they are used interchangeably. Such as, for example, in referencing "Non-legal passages in the Talmud and other Rabbinic writings that use descriptive allegories ".

Comment: @mevaqesh Just please don't spend too long worrying about a tag-wiki on a tag which might disappear in an hour by being merged into something else.

Comment: Why on Earth would any healthy sane individual commentlessly downvote a question for noting that misleading information is presented?

Comment: @DoubleAA, well, that one has no description, so we *may* wish to adopt whatever's decided here for whichever tag lasts.

Comment: @DoubleAA IMO, [tag:agada-stories-legends] should be renamed [tag:stories-legends]. It would then refer to all kinds of stories (as it currently does) without confusingly sounding like it's associated with a kind of Talmud passage, while [tag:aggadeta] would refer (as it currently does) to non-legal passages in the Talmud. Of course, these two tags would be overlapping, but not completely.

Comment: I'm not sure what "leaving that instead to the website itself" is getting at. We know that prior authorities have taken stands on this question. Maybe posts on Mi Yodeya will take their own stands; maybe they won't. I agree that the tag synonym, representing the Mi Yodeya website/community as a body, oughtn't.

Comment: I really think we need to resolve what scope each of the tags will have at the same time as (or before) resolving the present question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I meant that if someone wants to write a post arguing for one or the other, that is fine, but it should be done in its own post, not inserted into tag info.  I think we agree.

Comment: @mevaqesh I believe that we agree regarding substance; I'm suggesting that that passage is confusing and should be removed or replaced.

Answer (score 2):

I propose:

> Non-legal passages in the Talmud and similar rabbinic works

Comment: I think that non legislating is beter than non legal

Comment: @kouty note that "non-legal" is not the same as "illegal," in case that's your concern.

Comment: @IsaacMoses somewhat may be a legal topic with an aggadic purpose. legislating is more pointing the scope. BTW illegal is included in legal spectrum.

Answer (score -1):

suggestion

> Non legislating passages of Talmudic works

Answer (score -3):

Suggestion:

> Non-legal passages in the Talmud and other Rabbinic writings that often contain fantastic stories.

Comment: They often contain fantastic stories, but they often don't. And often non-_agad'ta_ contains fantastic stories (e.g. Exodus 10:23). So "that often contain fantastic stories" is at best a description, not a definition, of _agad'ta_ — and a poor one at that IMO. −1.

Comment: @msh210 `And often non-agad'ta contains fantastic stories (e.g. Exodus 10:23)` That is a totaly bogus claim. Aggadot are certainly characterized by the existence of fantastic stories, and indeed although I oversimplified earlier, the term is used disproportionately (from my experience) for such passages. The fact that one may find fantastic stories in a variety of places, from the Bible to the Harry Potter series, has no bearing.

Comment: (re your comment) So you're really disagreeing with my "but they often don't". Just one example off the top my head (from the _maseches_ I know best, not that that's saying much): In _Bavli M'gila_ what verse each _amora_ began his talk on _Ester_ with is perfectly believable, not fantastic.

Comment: @msh210 `So you're really disagreeing with my but they often don't` Nope. I have no idea why you would suggest that. Incidentally, your argument is circular in that it presupposes the definition that you are arguing. Not that that is particularly relevant.

Comment: Downvoters?????

Comment: (re your "Downvoters?????" comment) Votes on suggestions on Meta generally indicate agreement/disagreement rather than whether the suggestion is clear or the like.

Comment: @msh210 I would think that could be accomplished simply by upvoting a more appropriate answer.

Comment: @msh210 (the dramatic string of ?? was just to reach 15 chars)

Comment: Nonetheless, I think that's what people do (viz, downvote suggestions they don't agree with). And some downvotes may come from users who don't agree with *any* of the answers.

Comment: @msh210 oddly, the [relevant FAQ section](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) maps votes to agreement/disagreement specifically on [meta-tag:feature-request] posts. However, the behavior on our Meta, at least, clearly extends that mapping to all posts that propose something.